# How do I determine casperjs object is finished?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```
function sniffURLs(i){
   casper = require('casper').create({
      verbose: true;
      logLevel: "debug"
   });
   listener = function(resource, request){
      fs.write(outputpath,resource.url,'a');
   };
   casper.on("resource.requested", listener);
   casper.thenOpen(listOfURLS[i]).then(function(){
      this.waitFor(function(){
         this.scrollToBottom();
      });
   });
   casper.run();
}
var counter = 0;
for(counter=0;counter<listOfURLS.length;counter++){
   sniffURLs(counter);
}
```

I was wondering for the Loop, is there a way to determine when "casper.run()" has been called for the first url of the list, before it runs the function again for the second url and so forth? The reason I am doing this is because when casper is scrolling multiple webpages, some of the resource.urls get lost. I've looked into callbacks but not sure whats the best way to go about it.